# Unable to extend sub-menu with multiple options in each for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following apps scripts seems to be working for one sub-menu option (named Region which has further fuctions) created as custom menu for Google Sheets. However, when I try to extend it to one more sub-menu named "Category" I either get an error or the custom menu doesn't load in the UI.

```js
  function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tracker')
      .addItem('All Regions', 'AllRegions')
      .addItem('Clear Filters', 'clearallfilters')
         
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Regions')
          .addItem('Regions1', 'Region1')
          .addItem('Regions2', 'Regions2')
          .addItem('Regions3', 'Regions3')
          .addItem('Regions4', 'Regions4')
          .addItem('Regions5', 'Regions5')

.addToUi();
```

I tried the following to add the new sub-menu option which doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tracker')
      .addItem('All Regions', 'AllRegions')
      .addItem('Clear Filters', 'clearallfilters')
         
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Regions')
          .addItem('Regions1', 'Region1')
          .addItem('Regions2', 'Regions2')
          .addItem('Regions3', 'Regions3')
          .addItem('Regions4', 'Regions4')
          .addItem('Regions5', 'Regions5')

          .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Regions')
          .addItem('Category1', 'Category1')
          .addItem('Category2', 'Category2')
          .addItem('Category3', 'Category3')

.addToUi();
```

Comment: Lack of parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Tracker')
    .addItem('All Regions', 'AllRegions')
    .addItem('Clear Filters', 'clearallfilters')

    .addSeparator()
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Regions')
      .addItem('Regions1', 'Regions1')
      .addItem('Regions2', 'Regions2')
      .addItem('Regions3', 'Regions3')
      .addItem('Regions4', 'Regions4')
      .addItem('Regions5', 'Regions5')

      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Categories')
        .addItem('Category1', 'Category1')
        .addItem('Category2', 'Category2')
        .addItem('Category3', 'Category3')))

    .addToUi();
}
```

reference

[Custom Menus in Google Workspace](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)

Comment: Wow, that was such a miss. Thanks for correcting it. Total noob here and just learning. 

There is an issue though "Category" seems be part of "Regions" now, I want "Region" and "Category" as separate options under which there will their respective options such as region1, region2, region3 and category1, category2, category3.

Not sure why it being part or "Regions"

Comment: Looks like I fixed it with the clue you gave me. Closed the parenthesis after region5 and started category menu after that. Worked. Thank you